# Best SE community for questions about phone number spoofing

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about how easily phone numbers are spoofed and I'm not sure which site to post it to. Android Enthusiasts, Windows Phone, and Ask Different seem the closest fits to me but obviously deal with specific platforms rather than the actual phone call routing itself.

What SE site would my question fit on?

Comment: Your question probably already exists on the security web site.  Here is one example https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36949/24064

Comment: Just checked and it doesn't look like my question exists but it certainly looks like the right place to post it. Thanks!